# What are the advantages / disadvantages / best practices of using FileInfo.Encrypt and Memberships for Security

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security

I am looking into developing a compact management system that uses pure XML. However I am worried about security and user accounts.

### Original Plan

Move the XML file containing them out of the root of the website and using SHA2 to encrypt passwords.

### What I found

.Net 4.5 introduces FileInfo.Encrypt but I am worried about processing time and concurrent users to read it. It also has Memberships and Roles. What ae the advantages and disadvantages of each? What other best practices should I be following?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are not encrypting the passwords, sha is a hashing algorithm. Given that you are not sure about this I would strongly recommend against rolling your own authentication/authoriztion mechanism.

The build in .net membership stuff is excellent, and well proven. Stick with it and you can't go wrong.

Why are you encrypting the content on the server? This appears to be massively over the top, but if it's a requirement I would suggest storing the xml in an encrypted database - it will allow you to access the data far more efficiently, and will still meet your requirements.

Comment: I really wish that I could. I have written a CMS comparible to RedDot that integrated with AD. It stored XML in a field, and I would read and parse that XML to build the grid layout. However, the requirement I have now is pure XML. I am worried one-way encyption for passwords in an XML file located under App_Data (which is not served through IIS) is not enough. If SHA2 plus a SALT key is not enough to use with one-way encryption, what do you suggest?